# "Back your life it is". What does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following excerpt is from the story 'Adolf' by DH Lawrence, in which there is the expression ***'[Back your life it is](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ElEbAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT4827&lpg=PT4827&dq=%27but%20many,%20many%20were%20the%20heart%20searchings%27%20adolf%20by%20d%20h%20lawrence&source=bl&ots=F5ZrVdMDCU&sig=8uOmWyELMP9njKEmZJt23JnHuME&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJvuGGsZ_eAhWIMY8KHeGZBswQ6AEwCHoECAcQAQ#v=snippet&q=%27Back%20your%20life%20it%20is%27%2C%20said%20my%20father&f=true)'***. What does it mean? I googled to find a definition and looked up in many dictionaries, but all in vain. Is it an idiomatic expression or a fixed phrase—slang or dialect?

> When morning came, and it was light, I went downstairs. Opening the scullery door I heard a slight scuffle. Then I saw dabbles of milk all over the floor and tiny rabbit-droppings in the saucers. And there the miscreant, the tips of his ears showing behind a pair of boots. I peeped at him. He sat bright-eyed and askance, twitching his nose and looking at me while not looking at me.
>
> He was alive — very much alive. But still we were afraid to trespass much on his confidence.
>
> "Father!" My father was arrested at the door. "Father, the rabbit's alive."
>
> "**Back your life it is,**" said my father.
>
> "Mind how you go in."

Comment: I am having a hard time googling this phrase or even searching google books because of the general construction “`verb` back your life” (*take back*, *taking back*, *win back*, *give you back* and even *dream back*). My instinct is it means “you bet your life it is”, ie “with great certainty!” or “I knew it!”, etc. It’s probably a regionalism for the characters in Lawrence’s story. Good rustic folk and so on

Comment: @DanBron, Thank you. I also thought in the same way, but wanted to make sure. I hope someone will come up with more light.

Comment: The father may mean that the rabbit had eaten, and therefore decided to live. http://tomclarkblog.blogspot.com/2013/05/d-h-lawrence-rabbit-in-house.html

Comment: I agree with Dan Bron. I think "Back your life" means the same as "Bet your life".

Comment: I think the publisher may have issues. Please check this out:https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=180226  Lots of problems with punctuation and spelling etc.

Comment: Dan Bron is correct in his assessment. My grandmother's late boyfriend used to use these kinds of terms. As for Lambie's comment about Delphi having issues, while some of those are a matter of carelessness, most of those examples can be cleanly explained by the fact that the English language has changed a lot in the 100 years (almost) since "Adolf" was written or in the post's case, nearly 150 years since The Eternal Husband was written. After all, a hundred years ago was a foreign land.

Comment: It could be Yoda-ese.

Answer (score 6):

I think there is a simple answer to this.  There is an idiomatic exclamation in English:

When I want to re-enforce a factual claim, I might say this:

"That rabbit will still be in the scullery tomorrow, you can bet on it."  Or I could say, "... you can bet your life on it" and gain a greater impression of certainty.

Another word for 'bet' is 'back'.  You can bet on a horse or you can back a horse.

So I think it likely is that the father is saying that he is strongly shares the certainty.  If I am right, the verb "back" is imperative.  To the parent is telling the child he can be quite sure the rabbit is still alive:  so sure that he can back (i.e bet) his life  it is.

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer.

Comment: You back the horse, not the money.

Comment: Sure, but you use the money to back the horse. The backing is the bet.

Comment: Another usage, again by DH Lawrence: http://www.online-literature.com/dh_lawrence/england-my-england/5/

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a typographical error to me. I'm a native American English speaker, not a native British English speaker (as Lawrence was). However, from the context, I infer that it has the same meaning as the idiom "bet your life", and none of the sources I looked at (cambridge dictionary, the free dictionary - links #1 and #2 in my Google results) give "back your life" as an alternative phrase. I also found no evidence of contemporaneous usage, and non-idiomatic interpretations have to be fairly convoluted to make sense of it.

If it is a typo, you're not likely to find out much more about it. Depending on the publishing era and format of your copy, it could have happened in the writing, at the publisher/typesetter/printer, or during OCR and post-OCR spelling correction (the latter two operations might have been used to generate digital versions).

In my own reading, I find spelling errors pretty frequently, even in books that have been in print for a long time.

Edit: I’ve un-deleted this (incorrect) answer for posterity now that several abusive comments have been removed.

Comment: +1 @mRotten: A typographical error! A good inference, though I can't take it but with a pinch of salt. Most probably, it could be a regional variation of the idiom *bet your life* as *Dan Bron* mentioned in his comment above.

Comment: @mahmudkoya Your best bet is to look at a printed copy.

Comment: @michael.hor257k if you can find an edition that predates the typo.

Comment: My main suspect is OCR, so any printed edition would do.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Unless OCR was used to quickly digitize the book for a modern pressing.

Comment: mRotten, this is not a typographical error.  "Back your life it is!" was not a mistake. As answered above, it's a variation of, as you mentioned, "Bet your life." The reason why it wouldn't be offered as an alternative phrase is because "bet" and "back" are the parts that would be "give financial, material, or moral support to" which is functional to the usage of "bet" in the equivalent phrase. Calling this a typo is incorrect as a result.

Comment: mRotten, you're ignoring the definition of the word itself. Fact: "back" means "stake", and "stakes" refers to "bets" and "gambles".  Also, the fact it is used in this written work is already evidence it was used, so self-contradicting point there. If anecdotes were evidence, I could also use the fact I knew a man who used to use this before his passing. But anecdotal evidence is not evidence. Your claim it's just an error has less evidence and is merely an assertion without basis. At least the definitions line up for my side. 97 years makes a lot of difference in the evolution of English.

Comment: I don’te even know where to start. Literally none of your arguments are logical.

Comment: @SoraTamashii All you have to do is find another example of such usage. Until then, a typographical error remains the most likely explanation.

Comment: Well, a [1920 version of the story](https://books.google.com/books?id=tcxPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA272&lpg=PA272&dq="scullery+door"+scuffle) has the same excerpt, so I don't think this has anything to do with Delphi Classics (as was suggested in the comments on the question), although that doesn't mean that someone didn't make an error before that either.

Comment: @Laurel, good find. I kept seeing that too, but I couldn’t figure out if I was looking at the 1920s text, or if it was a representation of the 1920’s text. The words are searchable, so that implies OCR.

Comment: @mRotten You can scroll up to the top of the book (usually it's either the title page or the page after) to see when it was published. Some books on Google Books don't show this as part of the free preview ("snippet view"), so I search for the date I think that it was published. You're right not to trust the date that Google gives, since I've seen it be wrong countless times (and usually in etymology answers, when it's super important that the year not be off by 100 :P).

Comment: @Laurel, For sure, but it’s not the displayed year that I didn’t trust. I couldn’t tell whether I was looking at an image of the 1920’s text that has been annotated with the searchable words, or whether it was the OCR result displayed in an old-timey typeface. Does that make sense? But it’s unlikely that Delphi and Google made the same errors unless they used the same OCR algorithm or one relied on the other’s data. Anyway, I agree that it could be in the original.

Comment: Definitions are not evidence that it was used.

Comment: answer Tuffy gave is correct on this: it IS that phrase. No point in making another answer that says the exact same thing. I'll give Tuffy the link though so he can add it to his answer if he wants. Also, the fact you are looking at a usage of it is evidence it was used. If there wasn't this prior usage and a modern author used it as a variant for a region in their story, would you keep dismissing it as an error? I'd think not. This is truly no different.